# Angular routerLink and router.navigate update the url but not the content when same path structure

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router

I have a route that shows details for example `myappsite.com/library/abc123` the user can select an item to go to another route such as `myappsite.com/library/def456`. However, the url changes but the page doesn't react. I've tried this with the `routerLink` and a click event that calls `router.navigate` but they have the same reaction.

If these are changed to point to anything with a different `/library/<id>` structure it does fine.

per request:

route file config for that route:

```
  {
    path: 'library/:id',
    component: ProjectInformationComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
    data: { canReuseRoute: false, UserRole }
  }
```

how routerLink is used `routerLink="/library/{{library.id}}"`

I'm certain this worked before. I recently updated to v15

Comment: What does canReuseRoute do..? By default, Angular doesn’t ‘reload’ a component when you navigate to the same route, but you can override this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are subscribing to route parameters and not access them directly.